# could not open world file

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, sdf, world

[image: Rosanswers logo]

world file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <sdf version="1.6">
      <world name="default">
        <include>
          <uri>model://ground_plane</uri>
        </include>
        <include>
          <uri>model://sun</uri>
        </include>
        <model name="my_mesh">
          <pose>-80 -80 0  0 0 0</pose>
          <static>true</static>
          <link name="body">
            <visual name="visual">
              <geometry>
                <mesh><uri>file://model.dae</uri></mesh>
              </geometry>
            </visual>
          </link>
        </model>
      </world>
    </sdf>
```

this is file

```
<launch>
  <include file="$(find gazebo_ros)/launch/empty_world.launch">
    <arg name="world_name" value="city.world"/>
    <arg name="verbose" value="true"/>
  </include>
</launch>
```

this is my launch file

when I launch this it shows me an error as

```
[Err] [Server.cc:379] Could not open file[city.world]
```

but when spawn using

```
gazebo city.world
```

there is no error and it's spawning correctly.
what could be the problem?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/355928/could-not-open-world-file/) by [me_saw](https://answers.ros.org/users/52338/me_saw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2020-06-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

you need to give the path of "city.world":

arg name="world_name" value="/path/city.world"

---

Originally posted by [xibeisiber](https://answers.ros.org/users/54937/xibeisiber/) with karma: 137 on 2020-06-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [me_saw](https://answers.ros.org/users/52338/me_saw/) on 2020-06-27**:
Thanks, that was the problem

but now when I'm trying to launch it gives this error

```
[Wrn] [FuelModelDatabase.cc:248] URI not supported by Fuel [model.dae]
[Wrn] [SystemPaths.cc:464] File or path does not exist [""] [model.dae]
[Wrn] [FuelModelDatabase.cc:248] URI not supported by Fuel [file://model.dae]
[Wrn] [SystemPaths.cc:464] File or path does not exist [""] [file://model.dae]
[Err] [Visual.cc:3034] No mesh specified
```

**Comment by [xibeisiber](https://answers.ros.org/users/54937/xibeisiber/) on 2020-06-27**:
maybe you also need to set the path of model.dae...
like this:

```
          <geometry>
        <mesh>
          <uri>model://iscas_museum/meshes/ISCAS_museum.dae</uri>
        </mesh>
      </geometry>enter code here
```

**Comment by [me_saw](https://answers.ros.org/users/52338/me_saw/) on 2020-06-27**:
@xibeisiber  got it thank you